# what is the difference between programming language compiler and a database compiler?

Tags: database, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm more familiar with database compiler but not so with programming language compiler. I'm starting to read [Crafting a compiler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136067050) to help me better understand the programming language compiler. However, I'm wondering if anyone can offer a big picture of what difference might be? Thanks much!

Comment: Curious: most people here, myself included, are probably more familiar with programming language compiler than with database compiler. Perhaps you could briefly outline what you mean by a database compiler? There might be very little difference. In DB2, the SQL that's to be executed is (classically, on mainframes) precompiled to machine code in a query plan that is then executed when the query is run. That's the main thing that occurs to me when you say 'database compiler'. If that's valid, then a database compiler takes SQL (for example) and produces code the machine can run. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ A regular programming language compiler also takes in a textual form of a language (C, C++, C#, Fortran, Ada, Pascal, Java, …) and generates code that the machine can run.  Sometimes that the 'real' machine (C, C++, Fortran, Ada, usually but not always Pascal); sometimes that's a virtual machine — a program with standardized behaviour (Java and its JVM or Java Virtual Machine, for example).  If the analogy is inexact, then please explain what you mean by 'database compiler'.  The programming language compiler, though, takes source code and converts it so it can be run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler All good but DB2 compiles queries to a query plan, not to machine code.

Comment: @EJP: DB2 for zSeries, or DB2 LUW, or DB2 for iSeries?  My understanding, subject to correction, is that the zSeries systems can indeed convert queries to object code.  I reserve judgement on LUW and iSeries, though I'd not be surprised to find the LUW generates an intermediate 'query plan language' but that iSeries generates object code.  And if you're positive that it has changed for all systems, so be it — I don't keep up to date with all the technology in DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're compiling SQL with the database compiler. SQL is a fourth generation language (4GL).

So your compiler will spend a considerable amount of resources in determining the best way to fulfill the programmer's request. For example, a *select* statement could be performed using a variety of different query plans to get the data.

The programmer only instructs what is to be done, not exactly how to do it. It's the task of your database compiler to figure all this out.

In contrast, a programming language compiler (let's say for a 3GL) is just working through series of instructions dictated by the programmer.

A database compiler and programming language compiler will start out the same. That is, parsing instructions into a data structure while checking syntax.

After that, it diverges. The programming language compiler will try and generate statements native to the target platform. That might involve an assembly language (2GL) step, linking etc.

In contrast the database compiler (or RDBMS) will be concerned with figuring out the optimal way to process requests. Your database compiler will probably never have to deal with 2GLs and similar things.